# Passing a ResultSet into a Postgresql Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

Is it possible to pass the results of a postgres query as an input into another function?

As a very contrived example, say I have one query like

```
SELECT id, name
FROM users
LIMIT 50
```

and I want to create a function `my_function` that takes the resultset of the first query and returns the minimum id. Is this possible in pl/pgsql?

```
SELECT my_function(SELECT id, name FROM Users LIMIT 50); --returns 50
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a *cursor*, but that very impractical for computing a minimum.

I would use a **temporary table** for that purpose, and pass the table name for use in **dynamic SQL**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_min_id(_tbl regclass, OUT min_id int) AS 
$func$
BEGIN

EXECUTE 'SELECT min(id) FROM ' || _tbl
INTO min_id;

END  
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT id, name
FROM   users
LIMIT  50;

SELECT f_min_id('foo');
```

#### Major points

- The first parameter is of type `regclass` to prevent SQL injection. [More info in this related answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718).
- I made the temp table [`ON COMMIT DROP`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html) to limit its lifetime to the current transaction. May or may not be what you want.
- You can extend this example to take more parameters. [Search for code examples for dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-sql+plpgsql).

[**-> SQLfiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/52bef/1)

Answer (score 5):

I would take the problem on the other side, calling an [aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createaggregate.html) for each record of the result set. It's not as flexible but can gives you an hint to work on.

As an exemple to follow your sample problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myMin ( int,int ) RETURNS int AS $$
  SELECT CASE WHEN $1 < $2 THEN $1 ELSE $2 END;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STRICT IMMUTABLE;

CREATE AGGREGATE my_function ( int ) (
    SFUNC = myMin, STYPE = int, INITCOND = 2147483647 --maxint
);

SELECT my_function(id) from (SELECT * FROM Users LIMIT 50) x;
```

Comment: Just to be clear, in the simple case of min, your function/aggregate definitions wouldn't be necessary, right? You'd get the same effect from ```SELECT min(id) from (SELECT * FROM Users LIMIT 50) x```, I believe. So your answer doesn't answer the general question but shows how to define an arbitrary aggregation function and apply it to a result set. If I've misunderstood, please let me know.

Comment: @Sigfried Yes, it's just a theoretical sample as the question is.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to pass an array of generic type RECORD to a plpgsql function which is essentially what you are trying to do.

What you can do is pass in an array of a specific user defined [TYPE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtype.html) or of a particular table row type. In the example below you could also swap out the argument data type for the table name users[] (though this would obviously mean getting all data in the users table row).

```
CREATE TYPE trivial {
"ID" integer,
"NAME" text
}

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trivial_func(data trivial[])
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 

BEGIN
    --Implementation here using data
    return 1;

END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

Comment: That `CREATE TYPE` command fails as a syntax error on PostgreSQL version 9.4.4.

Comment: Thanks @AdamMackler - CREATE TYPE trivial AS { } in 9+

Comment: Can you please provide an example call of this function?

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no way to pass recordset or table into function (but I'd be glad if i'm wrong). Best I could suggest is to pass array:

```
create or replace function my_function(data int[])
returns int
as
$$
   select min(x) from unnest(data) as x
$$
language SQL;
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2267f/2)