# Pass a SELECT result as an argument to postgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table "UserState" with following fields:
id,
userid,
ctime,
state,
endtime.
I have a simple query:

```
SELECT userid FROM "UserState" WHERE ctime>'2014-07-14'::timestamp
```

AND I have a plpgsql function, which must take the result of this query as an argument:

```
get_timeinstate(SELECT userid FROM "UserState" WHERE ctime>'2014-07-14'::timestamp);
```

How to create function correctly to pass a query result as parametr there?
It's necessery to understand, that the function returns another SQL result and I need to use there "IN" condition:

```
$func$
BEGIN
 RETURN QUERY
 SELECT 
...myanotherquery...
 WHERE "UserState".userid IN (HERE I NEED TO INSERT MY QUERY RESULT)
END;
$func$
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219991/passing-a-resultset-into-a-postgresql-function

Comment: Sounds as if you are looking for `LATERAL`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pass the returned user_id set as array. Create the function to accept an integer array

```
create function get_timeinstate (
    user_id_set integer[],
    another_param...
```

Then call it passing the array generated by `array_agg`

```
get_timeinstate(
    (
        select array_agg(userid)
        from "UserState"
        where ctime>'2014-07-14'::timestamp
    ),
    another_param
);
```

Inside the function:

```
where "UserState".userid = any (user_id_set)
```

BTW if you are using plpgsql you can place the query inside the function and pass just the date:

```
create function get_timeinstate (
    p_ctime timestamp,
    another_param...
$func$
declare
    user_id_set integer[] := (
        select array_agg(userid)
        from "UserState"
        where ctime > p_ctime
    );
begin
    return query
    select 
    ...myanotherquery...
    where "UserState".userid = any (user_id_set)
end;
$func$
```

Comment: No, I can not, because I have about 30 functions and only one query, that must be passed as a parametr to all of them.
passing query result as a parametr I will be able to execute it only 1 time. And using this query in functions I will execute it 30 times. I need less time consumption.

Comment: @user3824666 Will the functions be used at once? If not you will be passing old data (as an int array `userid::int[]`, that is the solution). Or is it Ok to pass old data? Otherwise if the purpose is to _not repeat yourself_ then make that query a function itself and pass the `date` as argument.

Comment: The functions will be used at once, but I can't understand, how to work with an array. I'm not able to use IN operator while SELECTing, but I need it. 
I can't belive, that's impossible to pass a column as an argument.

Comment: @user3824666 It is possible to pass a column value. It is not possible to pass a set of values, other than in array form. I will post how.

Comment: What am I missing here? What's wrong with [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55418885/5579463).

Answer (score 20):

Just enclose in round brackets:

```
get_timeinstate(
  (
    SELECT userid FROM "UserState" WHERE ctime>'2014-07-14'::timestamp
  )
);
```

Comment: Best answer, clearly, but could you explain why that extra pair of brackets makes such a huge difference, please?

Comment: The additional parentheses encapsulate the entire subquery, ensuring that the result of the subquery is treated as a single entity, regardless of whether it returns a single row or multiple rows. Without these parentheses, the SQL engine could potentially interpret the SELECT statement as multiple distinct inputs to the `get_timeinstate()` function. The extra layer of parentheses provides clarity to the SQL engine, explicitly stating that the entirety of the subquery result should be treated as a singular input to the function.

Answer (score -2):

In my case I used like below to pass result of `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT get_timeinstate(userid) FROM "UserState" WHERE ctime>'2014-07-14'::timestamp
```

Answer (score -3):

Put select into round brackets or use ARRAY constructor (in this case you can change index in set-returning select)
Example:

```
with p as
(
    select id, xyz geometry from insar1.point
)
, extent as
(
    select st_extent(st_force2d(geometry)) geometry from p
)
INSERT INTO insar1.grid (geometry)
SELECT (
    ST_Dump(
      makegrid_2d(
        --maybe you need limit 1
        (SELECT e.geometry from extent e), --just use braces
        --this works too:
        --(ARRAY(SELECT e.geometry from extent e))[1],
         100,
         100
       )
    )
  ) .geom geometry
```