# How to pass an array of integers to sql IN() query

Tags: sql, node.js, arrays, postgresql

Sadly, I somehow was unable to find an answer for this for the past two hours... I am trying to pass an array of integers into an SQL IN query like so:

```
"SELECT id, bio, image_url, userhandle FROM users IN ([4,6,7,8])"
```

Of course this is not gonna work so i tried this, but it only works with string arrays. formattedUserIds is the array of integers.

```
"SELECT id, bio, image_url, userhandle FROM users IN ('" + formattedUserIds.join(",") + "')"
```

to clarify, basically what i need is to convert [4,6,7,8] -> 4,6,7,8 so i can pass it into the in clause like IN(4,6,7,8)
any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could pass-in a composite array parameter and `INNER JOIN` on it as an alternative to `WHERE IN`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466801/table-valued-parameter-equivalent-in-postgresql

Comment: I'm sorry, complete newbie at sql. How would i do this in my code? @Dai

Answer (score 2):

Use the [**`ANY`** construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16) instead and pass the array as is:

```
SELECT id, bio, image_url, userhandle
FROM   users
WHERE  id = ANY($user_ids);
```

Related:

- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)

Answer (score 0):

Working on the example provided by Dai, here is a way you can get this done. Use the IN Clause as follows

```
SELECT id, bio, image_url, userhandle 
  FROM users IN (select *
                   from unnest(ARRAY[4,6,7,8])
                )

demo
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=27ca1628fb40540f9dcf07b8c4625e6e
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function to parse array values to SQL return string

```
const parseArrayForSqlQuery = (stringArray: number[]) => {
  let returnString = '';
  stringArray.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (index > 0) {
      returnString = returnString + ',';
    }
    returnString = returnString + `${value}`; 
    // add an inner quotes if the values are string
  });
  return returnString;
}
```

Consider the below array should be pass to SQL statement

```
const arrayValues = [4,6,7,8];
```

Use the SQL statement like so

```
`SELECT id, bio, image_url, userhandle FROM users where users.id IN (${parseArrayForSqlQuery(arrayValues})`
```

Expected output

```
`SELECT id, bio, image_url, userhandle FROM users where users.id IN (4,6,7,8)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_in_set` that can work with string array. e.g. 1,2,3,4

```
SELECT id, bio, image_url, userhandle
FROM   users
WHERE  find_in_set(users.id, $user_ids);
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up just doing

```
  "SELECT id, bio, image_url, userhandle FROM users WHERE id IN (" + formattedUserIds.toString() + ")"
```

Thank you!

Comment: I downvoted this answer because of the risk of SQL injection (and because of the possibility that using variadic `IN` won't be able to take advantage of cached execution plans). What guarantees do you have that `formattedUserIds.toString()` will **always** return a syntactically correct substring? What if `formattedUserIds` is empty? If you're formatting strings using culture/locale-specific formatting then you might see commas as digit-grouping characters which will break your query. And so on and so on.